# delete the last row and the last columns of a dynamic array in c

Tags: c

I have created a dynamic 2d array in C declared as a pointer array. How do I delete the last row both in the pointer array and the row it points to ?

if i will use the

```
    arr=realloc(arr , i*sizeof(int *));
```

and the i is 3 (4 rows-1)

are the columns in the 4th row gonna delete or i need to use something like this ?

```
    arr[i]=realloc(arr[i] ,sizeof(char));
    arr=realloc(arr , i*sizeof(int *));
```

if it is correct or i need to use 
        free()

---

here is my code but i want to delete the last row with the columns and i dont know how

```
int main(void) {
    char **arr,str[500];
    int i=0,j,min_str_pos;
    long min;
    arr = malloc(sizeof(int *));
    arr[i] = malloc(500*sizeof(char));
    do {
            printf("Enter a string (or just press <ENTER> to exit): \n");
            fgets ( str, 500, stdin );
            if (strcmp(str, "\n")) {
                    strcpy(arr[i],str);
                    i++;
                    arr=realloc(arr , (i+1)*sizeof(int *));
                    arr[i] = malloc(500*sizeof(char));
            }
    } while (strcmp(str, "\n"));
```

Comment: `sizeof char` is useless, the result is always `1`.

Comment: You need to show the code that does the allocation.  Do you have an array of pointers plus a separate allocation for each row (so you index the array with `array[i][j]`), or do you have a single allocation of NxM items that you're indexing with `array[i*width+j]`, or what?  You get different answers depending on what you're using.

Comment: i posted the code and the thing i want to do is to dlete the last row with columns from the 2d array generated by do while command after the while command

Comment: It would help if the code you posted actually **compiles**. Also it doesn't belong posted in an answer; it belongs up *here* in the question unless you solved your problem and are actually posting an answer.

Comment: @effeffe: It's at least as useful as the literal `1`, and has the added benefit of being self-documenting.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit if I see a `malloc` with just a simple number as parameter (no `sizeof`) I already know that an array of `char` will be allocated because `char` is the only type that always have `1` byte as size. I would agree if there would be more types with the same fixed size.

Comment: @effeffe: It's just a bit of self-documentation that loses you absolutely nothing. "Why is the number `1` there?" vs "Ah, that argument is for the size of the element type. [I don't care that it's equal to 1.]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I fixed up your code so it would at least compile:

```
int main(void) {
    char **arr,str[500];
    int i = 0;
    arr = malloc(sizeof(int *));
    arr[i] = malloc(500*sizeof(char));
    do {
        printf("Enter a string (or just press <ENTER> to exit)");
        fgets (str, 500, stdin );
        if (strcmp(str, "\n")) {
            strcpy(arr[i], str);  
            i++;
            arr=realloc(arr , (i+1)*sizeof(int *));
            arr[i] = malloc(500*sizeof(char));
        }
    } while (strcmp(str, "\n"));
}
```

Note that `arr[i]=str;` is not the proper way to copy a string. Instead use `strcpy(arr[i], str);`.

To delete the last row of the array, simply use:

```
free(arr[i]);
```

Now by removing the last column of the array, do you mean you want to remove the last `char` from each `string` in the array?