# using qsort to sort alphabetically strings of a 2d array

Tags: c

how can i use qsort to sort alphabetically  strings of a 2d array which has strings for a example if i have an array of 4 rows and every row has a string of >=50 characters ...how can i use the qsort function to sort string alphabetically ?

i used this

```
            qsort(arr, i, 500*sizeof(arr[0]), compare);
            for (j=0; j<i; j++) {
                    printf("%s\n",arr[j]);
            }
```

and the comparator i used is

```
            int compare (const void * a, const void * b ) {
                    return strcmp(a, b);
            }
```

but it gives me segmentation fault error while trying to compile

Comment: can you show your definition of arr?

Comment: Are you sure `it gives you a segmentation fault while trying to compile`? It sounds like a compiler bug, which is unlikely. You probably encounter it during run time and not compile time

Comment: Should it not be `return strcmp(*(char **)a, *(char **)b);`?

Comment: i made a 2d array with strings and i try to sort them alphabetically with qsort command

Comment: @user1809300 We already know that. Tried what I proposed in my previous comment?

Comment: i tried it and it gives me : too few arguments to function ‘strcmp’

Comment: @user1809300 Well, maybe I've made a typo, fix that. Don't copy-paste. (Well, I found that - remove the outer parentheses.)

Comment: Fwiw, `arr` is a `char **`, and in case you're looking for more code, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012249/delete-the-last-row-and-the-last-columns-of-a-dynamic-array-in-c/14014067#14014067) for the gory underneath. Also, I'm hoping he meant "while trying to **run** the program" rather than "while trying to compile" or there are some serious issues with his toolchain.

Comment: sure its an array,  but WHAT is its definition,  it is important when you use qsort.  that 3rd parameter is dependent on the definition of arr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This way it would work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define size 10
int compare (const void * a, const void * b ) {
  return strcmp(*(char **)a, *(char **)b);
}
int main () {
    char *arr[size];
    char buf[1000];
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
      arr[i]=strdup (gets (buf)); // using gets is risky because it can write past buf
    }
    qsort (arr, size, sizeof (char*), compare);
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
      printf ("%s\n", arr[i]);
      free (arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: however, the idea of 2d arrays got lost. But was'nt clearly defined either.